# Visibility bug with group box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, groupbox

I have a form with 2 radio buttons and for each of them, one group box is related when they are checked (radio button 1 shows group box 1 and hide group box 2 / radio button 2 shows group box 2 and hides group box 1).
It works perfectly fine but I need to force the display of one group box depending of which server the user connect and when I do that I'm hiding radio buttons to not leave any choice for the user.
So I do someting like that :

```
 if(m_lastSelectedNode.Text == "server1")
                {
                    label1.Visible = false;
                    label2.Visible = true;
                    MainForm_GroupBox_1.Visible = false;
                    MainForm_GroupBox_2.Visible = true;
                }
 else if (m_lastSelectedNode.Text == "server2")
                {
                    label1.Visible = true;
                    label2.Visible = false;
                    MainForm_GroupBox_1.Visible = true;
                    MainForm_GroupBox_2.Visible = false;
       
                }
 else
                {
                    label1.Visible = false;
                    label2.Visible = false;
                    MainForm_GroupBox_1.Visible = true;
                }
```

So what happen here is when i'm connecting to server1 for showing only groupbox 2 it doesn't work and moreover if i come back to a classic server and trying to do the regular thing with radio button, groupbox2 won't be shown (no problem on group box 1) but if i'm first connecting to a regular server, doing the regular thing with radio button for showing group box 2 and then connecting to the server 1, it'll work the way i wanted.

I don't understand how is it possible, i don't have issue with label that hide radio button and for the two group box it's not an overlap issue so any suggestion here ?

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean when you say connect to server 1? I believe you are talking about selecting them from screen. I have a hunch that your code is reaching the else block initially which could be debugged.

Comment: Basically a TreeView is displayed on the form and when the user double click on a server the method ConnectToWorkspace occur and the code i sent is in this method.

Comment: I have verified and each block is reach properly by the method depending of the server that have been chosen.

Comment: OK, so what do you notice when you debug the first selection?

Comment: Like i said, it depends what i do first when i open the form, if the first thing i do is the block 1 (server1)  then for all the session i won't be able to see the group box 2 even if i change my server after (bc you can change the server during your session) otherwise if i do the block 3 (else) first and change the groupbox to 2 with radiobutton, it'll work like i want for the rest of the session even if you connect to server 1 after.

Comment: Didn't mention block 2 (else if server 2) because it shows group box 1 properly without any issue with any case.

Comment: I even debugged the visible parameter of both groupbox and the are changed like it is write in the code but don't know why even with visible at "true" the groupbox 2 as a different behaviour depending if i do the checked change event with radio button first or the connection of server where i force the visible parameter of groupbox 2 to true. The checkedchanged event code is only setting the visible variable of both groupbox to true or false this is why i don't understand something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by giving up the visible parameter. I set both group box visible to true by default and I choose to change the location for hiding them instead of using visible. I guess it's not optimal but it works.